# Unable to render image in Node JS

Tags: node.js

I'm generating Dynamic QR code image from my JAVA server using API service, and it generates successfully using the POSTMAN. But while calling the same API in `axios.post` it returns the response but unable to send this using `res.send(response.data)`

```
exports.getCollectionQR = function (req, res) {
  var qrcodegene = common.internalServiceURL + "/codeGenerator/"
  axios.post(qrcodegene, null, {
    params: {
      code: req.params.mid
    }
  }).then(function (response) {
    //console.log(response);    
    res.status(200).type('png').send(response.data);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    //res.status(error.response.status).send(JSON.stringify(error.response.data));
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Try setting: { responseType: 'arraybuffer' } in axios configuration.

Comment: { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }  isthe correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solutions

{ responseType: 'arraybuffer' } need to put in configuration like

```
axios.post(qrcodegene, null, {
    params: {
      code: req.params.mid
    },
responseType: 'arraybuffer'
  })
```

Also on the res.send needs to be

```
res.status(200).type('png').send(Buffer.from(response.data,"utf8"));
```

This will help someone who wants to show a dynamic image as a response in API